# What is the best way of combining audio and visual data to make predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, rnn, machine-learning-model, convolutional-neural-network

I am trying to predict the probability of a disease by using audio and images, the audio and the images do not come from the same source. I am thinking of combining the outputs (maybe average them) of two models one utilizing image data to calculate the probability the other using audio data. I am feeling unsure of this approach as I will not be able to verify the final combined output. Will the outcomes be reliable, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fuse the image and audio data. You can fuse in different ways:

1) Early fusion - fusion at feature level

2) Late fusion - fusion at output level (similar to your idea)

Here is some papers for your reference:

Look, Listen and Learn
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08168.pdf

Learn to Combine Modalities in Multimodal Deep
Learning
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11730.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that I am using audio and the visual data from two different datasets and I will not be able evaluate the accuracy of the final output.

Comment: It would probably help if you could give some idea about the datasets and their labels. There are also papers on weak supervision if that is applicable.